# Autocomplete Google Maps - results in several languages

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I would like to have the possibility if a username searches in my application Moscow, the Autocomplete form could return "Moscow", "Moscú", or even "Москва́" as possible locations. Then I can find in my database all these matches.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the language set in the browser or override it. See [Localization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization).

You can use the `language` parameter in your request to change the language of response. See Going through [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests).